# Not connecting via usb since latest update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb, connection-issues

Since the latest update on Galaxy S3 (now have Jelly Bean 4.3) my phone will not connect via USB to the USB port on my car radio. It connected before the update. What can I do to correct problem?

Comment: It could be that its recognizing the USB cable as a computer and not just an outlet for power. Is there any indication that you are getting power? Did you try the same cable on a different device?

Answer (score 0):

What protocol does the connection to your car radio use? I can't exactly speak for the GS3 but this is for stock Android so it may be similar. Go into Storage under Settings and hit the menu button (or the menu overflow) then select USB connection (or similar), make sure MTP (you probably need this one) and any other protocols you need are checked. There may also be a Mount USB option present if that the former does not work.